# Dynamic Textview scrollbar not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

I have created a textview dynamically and want to make it scrollable.

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = parseLayoutParams(
                frameMargins, context);
tv.setText(Utility.getpropertyString(controls.getText()));
final String textColor = Utility.getpropertyString(controls.getTextcolor());
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
tv.setTextSize(12);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
tv.setTextSize(tSize);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
tv.setMaxLines(controls.getMaxlines());
tv.setTag(controls.getTagId());
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
tv.setVisibility(controls.getVisibility());
tv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(isScrollable);
tv.setScroller(new Scroller(context));
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());         
tv.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);
```

But I am not able to see scrollbar in the textview niether when not scrolling nor when we scroll it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ferran noted, *initializeScrollBars()* has been removed. See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37007504) for the bug report and the rationale for its removal. As far as I can tell, there is no other strictly programmatic way to specify scollbars for a view. All paths go through XML. :-(

I think that Ferran's answer is a good way to go: it works, is easy to understand and should be easy to document. There are, however, other ways to programatically create a *TextView* with scrollbars with a slight assist from styles.

**For API 21 and above**
Define a style called "ViewWithScrollBars" as follows:

```
<style name="ViewWithScrollbars">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

We can now use the four-argument constructor for *TextView* to apply the style.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this, null, 0, R.style.ViewWithScrollbars);
```

This method will create a *TextView* with scrollbars. There is at least one caveat however. When a *TextView* is created with a single argument

```
new TextView(Context)
```

The constructor telescopes through other constructors that add additional arguments. One of these constructors is defined as follows:

```
public TextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.textViewStyle);
}
```

The third argument `com.android.internal.R.attr.textViewStyle` is an Android internal style that will pick up a default *textViewStyle* from the theme. The call I suggest uses zero for the third argument, so any *textViewStyle* defined in the theme will not be applied.

A reasonable fix for this might be to do the following:

```
tv = new TextView(this, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, R.style.ViewWithScrollbars);
```

Unfortunately, if the third argument (*defStyleAttr*) is defined in the theme, then the fourth argument (*defStyleRes*) is not used. As a result, the scrollbars will not appear.

If you use *textViewStyle* then you will have to make adjustments or just use the following approach.

**For all APIs**
Using the style "ViewWithScrollBars" from above, we can define a `ContextThemeWrapper` that will install scrollbars into the theme that will be used to create the *TextView*.

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ViewWithScrollbars); // "this" is the Activity
tv = new TextView(ctw);
```

I refer you to an article by Chris Banes entitled ["Theme vs Style"](https://chris.banes.dev/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/) that explains how theme overlays work.

The following puts all this together.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // This will actually work for API 21 and above.
            ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ViewWithScrollbars);
            tv = new TextView(ctw);
        } else {
            tv = new TextView(this, null, 0, R.style.ViewWithScrollbars);
        }
        tv.setText(R.string.lorem);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
        tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        tv.setMaxLines(7);
        tv.setTag(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        tv.setScroller(new Scroller(this));
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tv.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(tv);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

From Api 21, the View scrollbar visibility is only reserved for xml layouts because an important function called `initializaScrollBars` was removed due to an issue while passing `TypeArray` variable as a parameter.

So, to accomplish what you need programmatically, you can do it like this

Create an xml layout called `scrolltextview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Now, to create it programmatically

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.scrolltextview, null, false);
    // now decorate it as your needs
    tv.setText(m);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv.setTextSize(23);
    ...
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    // this is needed only if you want to show scrollbar also when text is not scrolling
    tv.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);
    // thecontainer = the layout you want to add your new textview
    thecontainer.addView(tv);
```